# What's this power supply cable called?

Tags: power-supply

What's the second cable from the left called? The one with yellow and black cables?

[image]

Comment: You can search such cases yourself on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:WhatLinksHere/File:ATX-Netzteil.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Molex Mini-fit 4 pin

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molex_connector

Answer (score 3):

Otherwise known as the Intel P4 power connector.

Intel P4 processors needed more 12v power to operate, they added the socket for this on the motherboard, in addition to the 20-24 pin motherboard power connector.

Can be used for other things.

.